# Why are some icons gray when editing Target Platform contents in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Here is a screenshot where some icons are colored and some are gray:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Exactly what dialog is this? What version of Eclipse?

Comment: When editing a Target Definition and double clicking on a software site to change contents from that site. This is Oxygen 3a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yellow folder objects represent Features.

The grayed objects represent p2 installer `IInstallableUnit` objects. Internally the code calls these 'noref features' - not sure what this means.

The code that determines the image is `org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.shared.target.StyledBundleLabelProvider`